# Associate requests with active page

Tags: google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

I'm working on a browser extension (compatible with Chrome, FF, Opera, and Edge) and I'm trying to figure out how to associate requests to domains outside of the current page.  For example, when you go to google.com a lot of requests to domains other than google.com occur such as to gstatic.com.

An extension like NoScript shows all of the requested domains that a page made and lets you allow or deny.  I'm trying to get a similar functionality.

Is this something that can be done in the content script or is there some way to keep state information in the background script that I can then display in the popup?  Obviously it's possible but I'm just not seeing which callback I can use.

Comment: As you can see in webRequest API documentation you can use the `tabId` property.

Comment: I saw that but didn't think it would work because the same tab can be reused.  Is there a way to tell when a brand new page is being loaded and not just a request such as with ajax?  webNav looks promising but has some caveats with relation to webRequest and tab ids.

Comment: I don't understand why you think it won't work. It will, and it works. You can also use `type` to differentiate the requests.

Comment: "Not work" probably wasn't the best term.  If I'm on a tab (lets say id = 1) and goto google it will list all the request with tabid = 1.  If I then use the same tab to goto bing.com it will still say tabid = 1 but this is a new page with different associated requests.  How can I make that differentiation between requests from google and bing?

Comment: Not sure why that matters, but you can easily maintain a `Map` of tabId->url relation and update in your webRequest callbacks when `type` is `main_frame`, and delete from it in chrome.tabs.onRemoved, chrome.tabs.onReplaced.

Comment: It matters if you want to know what requests a particular url is doing.  Tracking tab activity isn't that useful for my particular purpose.  I'll give the mapping a go but the problem I see with that is that the requests don't have to go to the page url (i.e. google.com makes requests to gstatic.com and googleapis.com).  main_frame I think will help what I'm trying to do.  Thanks!